# Sequencing of function parameter destruction

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, function-calls, sequencing

According to C++14 [expr.call]/4:

> The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns.

This seems to imply that a parameter's destructor must run before the code which called the function goes on to use the function's return value.

However, this code shows differently:

```
#include <iostream>

struct G
{
    G(int): moved(0) { std::cout << "G(int)\n"; }
    G(G&&): moved(1) { std::cout << "G(G&&)\n"; }
    ~G() { std::cout << (moved ? "~G(G&&)\n" : "~G()\n"); }

    int moved;
};

struct F
{
    F(int) { std::cout << "F(int)\n"; }
    ~F() { std::cout << "~F()\n"; }
};

int func(G gparm)
{
    std::cout << "---- In func.\n";
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    F v { func(0) };
    std::cout << "---- End of main.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output for gcc and clang , with `-fno-elide-constructors`, is (with my annotations):

```
G(int)               // Temporary used to copy-initialize gparm
G(G&&)               // gparm
---- In func.
F(int)               // v
~G(G&&)              // gparm
~G()                 // Temporary used to copy-initialize gparm
---- End of main.
~F()                 // v
```

So, clearly `v`'s constructor runs before `gparm`'s destructor.  But in MSVC, `gparm` is destroyed before `v`'s constructor runs.

The same issue can be seen with copy-elision enabled, and/or with `func({0})` so that the parameter is direct-initialized. `v` is always constructed before `gparm` is destructed. I also observed the issue in a longer chain, e.g. `F v = f(g(h(i(j())));` did not destroy any of the parameters of `f,g,h,i` until after `v` was initialized.

This could be a problem in practice, for example if `~G` unlocks a resource and `F()` acquires the resource, it would be a deadlock. Or, if `~G` throws, then execution should jump to a catch handler without `v` having been initialized.

My question is: does the standard permit both of these orderings? . Is there any more specific definition of the sequencing relationship involving parameter destruction, than just that quote from expr.call/4 which does not use the standard sequencing terms?

Comment: If the destruction was mandatory at the end of the function, wouldn't this prevent copy-elision in a lot of cases (if you construct the returned object using the parameter)?

Comment: @Holt I don't think it's a copy-elision context, returning a parameter. (But even if it is, that's no problem, as it would get elided into the return value, so there is no destruction of the parameter any more)

Comment: I meant returning an object constructed using the parameter - Let's say I have `X f(A a)` which return `X(a)`, if I do `X x(f(A()))`, compiler will likely construct `x` in place, but if `A()` was meant to be destroyed at the end of `f()`, how would this be done (you would need to construct `X` from `a`, then destroy `a`, then copy `X`, no?)?

Comment: @Holt in `X x(f(A()))`, `A()` is the argument, not the parameter. The argument is destroyed at the end of the full-expression. The parameter is the symbol `a` inside `f`, which is copy-initialized from the argument.  If that copy-initialization is elided then the argument is never destroyed ; there is the construction `A()` and the destruction of the parameter.

Comment: I was talking about the elision of `x`'s constructor, not `a`'s - If `a` has to be destroyed at the end of `f`, how can you construct `X` in-place using `a` without modifying the order in the observable behavior (but maybe copy-elision is allowed to do that?)? What I try to say is that without elision, the behavior should be (I think) `X(const A&)` -> `~A()` -> `X(X&&)`, and with the elision it becomes `X(const A&)` -> `~A()`, so in the first case, `a` is destroyed before the construction (by copy) of `x`, while in the second case `a` is destroyed after - But maybe this is allowed?

Comment: OK,I see what you are saying now. MSVC uses the `X(A&) -> ~A -> X(X&&)` order, gcc uses `X(A&) -> X(X&&) -> ~A`. So MSVC's elision does change the ordering between `~A` and construction of the caller's `X`.  But I think that is OK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually I can answer my own question... didn't find an answer while searching before writing it, but then searching again afterwards did find an answer (typical huh).

Anyway:  this issue is [CWG #1880](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1880) with the following note:

> **Notes from the June, 2014 meeting:**
>
> WG decided to make it unspecified whether parameter objects are destroyed immediately following the call or at the end of the full-expression to which the call belongs.

although the issue 1880 remains open.

The subject was also visited by [P0135 - guaranteed copy-elision](https://wg21.link/p0135) which made it implementation-defined, rather than unspecified. In C++17 (N4659) the text is:

> It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.

There is more background information here: [Late destruction of function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453898/)

---

Note: The definition of *full-expression* can be found in C++14 [intro.execution]/10:

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression. [...] If a language construct is defined to produce an implicit call of a function, a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition.

So `F v { func(0) };` is the enclosing *full-expression* for `gparm` (even though it's a declaration and not an expression!).

Comment: Uh huh, exactly what is the full-expression in the declaration `F v { func(0) };`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `F v { func(0) };` is the *full-expression*. See [intro.execution]/10

Comment: Thanks,if that's a definition then I think you should quote that, because the answer's not meaningful without such definition. ;-)

Comment: This reminds me, we need  a way to generalize reference-capture lifetime-extension in C++.

Comment: Maybe `v { func(0) }` is *full-expression*?