# Why would temporary lifetime extension cause destructor to be called multiple times?

Tags: c++, c++11, lifetime, temporary, xvalue

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Temp {
    public:
    Temp() { cout << "Temp()" << endl;}
    ~Temp() { cout << "~Temp()" << endl;}
};

Temp GetTemp() {
     cout << "GetTemp" << endl;
    return Temp();
}

Temp TakeTemp(Temp temp) {
    cout << "TakeTemp" << endl;
    return temp;
}


int main()
{
    TakeTemp(GetTemp());

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran `TakeTemp(GetTemp());`, the output looks like

```
GetTemp                                                                                                                                                        
Temp()                                                                                                                                                         
TakeTemp                                                                                                                                                       
~Temp()                                                                                                                                                        
~Temp()
```

Note that `~Temp()` is called twice here (but only 1 temp obj is constructed). This seems odd since 1) the temp variable returned by `GetTemp()` is supposed to have its lifetime extended to the full expression, and 2) since we return `temp` directly in `TakeTemp`, return value optmization will reuse the same object.

Can anyone explain why there are multiple dstor calls here?

(Note that if we place more layers of TakeTemp() around, the number of dstor calls grows proportionally.)

Comment: Added full program there.

Comment: Also there is no lifetime extension here (in the parts of the code posted so far). The lifetime of a temporary is until the end of the full-expression.

Comment: Isn't the full expression `TakeTemp(GetTemp());`? In that case the same temp variable will live all the way thru.

Comment: Yes that is the full expression. The problem is you use the word "extend" to describe what its natural lifetime was

Comment: The implicit copy constructor is being called.  Add `Temp(Temp const&) { cout << "Temp(Temp const&)" << endl;}`

Answer (score 5):

Your function `TakeTemp` takes its argument by value, and returns the argument by value.

You're making a copy there, hence there are now two `Temp` objects to delete.

The two objects you are seeing destructed are the return values of the two functions called here:

```
TakeTemp(GetTemp());
         ^ returns a Temp
^ returns a Temp
```

Comment: Why is cstor only called once then?

Comment: @OneZero Because you are not logging copy / move constructors.

Comment: @OneZero: because you only trace the default constructor and the copy uses the copy constructor.

Comment: Be advised that putting anything (e.g. logging) in the copy constructor will not be guaranteed to be visible at all, and since C++17 actually will never show up in this case.

Comment: Go add a copy constructor of the form `Temp(const Temp& other) { cout << "Temp(other)" << endl;}` too see it in your program output.  Without that, the compiler generates a default copy constructor for you.

Comment: @rubenvb It will show up at lest once because copying of function parameter `temp` can not be elided.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++17 terminology, the two objects are:

1. The function parameter `Temp temp;`
2. The return value of `TakeTemp`.

The function call `GetTemp()` is a prvalue. Since it is the argument to a function call, its *result object* is the matching parameter `Temp temp`. The *temporary materialization conversion* is applied at the point of construction of `Temp temp`.

Note that there is no temporary created inside the `GetTemp()` function. The statement `return Temp();` does not mean to create an object; it's giving the arguments that will be used to ultimately create an object later. There is no object created until a prvalue is materialized.

Then, the exection of `return temp;` creates the second object. This differs from `return Temp();` because `temp` is an lvalue, not a prvalue.  The return value object of the function call to `TakeTemp` is created using `temp` as the initializer. This is not a copy elision context.  If you add a copy constructor to `Temp` you will see the message of copy construction of that object.

To recap, the order of events is:

- `GetTemp` body is entered
- `GetTemp` return statement is executed, which initializes the parameter `Temp temp`
- `GetTemp` body exits (destroying any local variables if there were any)
- `TakeTemp` body is entered
- `TakeTemp` return statement is executed, which initializes the return value object for `TakeTemp`
- `TakeTemp` body exits  (execution returns to `main`)
- { The parameter `Temp temp` is destroyed
- { The return value object of `TakeTemp` is destroyed

The lifetime of `Temp temp` is the lifetime of a function parameter; it is destroyed after the function returns.

The lifetime of the return value of `TakeTemp` is a temporary object lifetime, so it lasts until the end of the full-expression.

Note that there is a quirk with function parameter lifetime: [it is implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824814/sequencing-of-function-parameter-destruction) whether this is destroyed immediately following the call, or at the end of the full-expression.  So the last two steps in my list above could occur in either order.  On my installation of g++ 8.2.1, the function parameter is actually the later of the two destructors.